# Why does the CPU load dropped in the last days?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

[image]

Anybody has a hint? I didn't change anything in the machine (except for the security updates), and the sites hosted there didn't suffer a significant change in connections.

May be Google changed something in their infrastructure? Coincidentally, it was an issue with the Cloud DNS ManagedZone these days: they charged me with $ 920 for half month usage, and it was an error (they counted thousands of weeks of usage too) so they recently changed back to $ 0,28. May be there was some process that indeed used the Cloud DNS by error and thus consumed CPU power, and they corrected now?

I wish to know what is happening from someone that knows what going on in GC. Thank you.

Comment: Did the security updates coincide with the start of lower CPU usage? Suspect the DNS charges are a simple billing error, not an indication of more DNS activity.

Comment: Well, actually, not. There was no security updates before the lowering. Nobody else has seen something like that in their Compute Engine?

Comment: Mine is a g1-small instance with 1 shared CPU (Intel Haswell) and 1.7 GB of RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU utilization reporting is now more accurate from a VM guest perspective as it doesn't include virtualization layer overhead anymore. It has nothing to do with Cloud DNS.

See this issue for some extra context:
https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=281

Comment: Thank you. That's the explanation I was looking for. I think that Google should have explained that to everyone. I had no clue about what's going on. I don't understand why someone has downvoted ny question.